# Some parts of HTML form POST not available in Arduino application

Tags: html, post, arduino, esp8266

I'm not an Arduino programmer by trade and I haven't worked with HTML in several years. I have a project that is running Arduino code on an ESP8266 with a web front-end. I am trying to add the option to change the wi-fi password, but that part of the form does not seem to be available to the code.
Have I made a simple error here?

```
/********************************************************************
 * Name:        DiffPressureServer
 * Author:      Rod Naugler
 * Version:     0.1
 * Date:        18 Sept 2018
 * Copyright:   All rights reserved
 * Description: Arduino IDE script designed to be uploaded to Sonoff
 *              Basic WiFi switch. Communicates with SPD810-125PA
 *              differential presseure sensor over the I2C bus.
 *              The relay can be triggered either by a differential
 *              pressue in excess of the set point, or bythe button
 *              in the web interface. The web interface also displays
 *              the current differential pressure, the set point, and
 *              the relay status.
 ********************************************************************/

//Include the ESP8266 WiFi library to allow the unit to act as access point
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//Include the ESP8266 Webserver library to allow us to process the web forms
  #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
//Include the EEPROM library to allow setpoints to persist across reboots
  #include <EEPROM.h>

//Include the Wire library to allow I2C communication with the sensors.
  #include <Wire.h>

//This is the station ID and password to access the pressure sensor with your WiFi device
  const char *ssid = "HAWK-EYE-DP-Sensor";
  const char *password = "thereisnospoon";
  char storedPassword[64];

// Create an instance of the server on standard port 80
  ESP8266WebServer server(80);

//Create a string to hold the received header
  String header;

//Create a string to show the state of the relay and default to off
  char* outputRelayState;

//Create constants for the two GPIOs we'll be using.
  const int outputLED = 13;      //Active low
  const int outputRelay = 12;    //Active high

//Define the i2c address to work with
  int i2cAddress = 0x25;

//A long to hold the returned values
  float i2cValue = 00;

//A long to hold the sensor temperature
  float i2cTemp = 00;
  float i2cTempConv = 200;

//A long to hold the sensor scale value
  float i2cScale = 00;

//A byte to hold the CRC value
  byte i2cCRC = 00;

//A long to hold the high setpoint
  float highSet = 00;
//A long to hold the low setpoint
  float lowSet = 00;
//Define the maximum set value
  #define MaxSet 125
//Define the minimum set value
  #define MinSet -125

//Define a BOOL to hold the automatic state  
  char* automatic;

//A character string to hold our webpage
  char html[3000];

//A character string to hold the fan button code
  char fanButton[100];

//Variables for change password function
  char* errorMessage="";
  char charBuf[50];

//Setup everything
  void setup() {

  //Start the eeprom with 512Bytes reserved
    EEPROM.begin(512);

  //Get the first four bytes as a float for low set
    EEPROM.get(0,lowSet);

  //Get the next four bytes as a float for high set
    EEPROM.get(sizeof(lowSet),highSet);

  //Get the stored WiFi password
    EEPROM.get((sizeof(lowSet)+sizeof(highSet)),storedPassword);
    if(strcmp(storedPassword,"ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ")){
      strcpy(storedPassword, password);
    }

  //Start with the output Relay off  
    outputRelayState="off";

  //Start in automatic mode
    automatic = "checked";

  //Open the i2c path. This uses the TX pin as Data and RX pin as clock
    Wire.begin(1,3);

  //Set the DP Sensor to Triggered Read Mode
    Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAddress);
    Wire.write(0x36);
    Wire.write(0x15);
    Wire.endTransmission();

  // Prepare the output LED
    pinMode(outputLED, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(outputLED, HIGH);

  // Prepare the output relay
    pinMode(outputRelay, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(outputRelay, LOW);


  // Start the WiFi Access point
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  // Setup the url handler
    server.on("/", handleRootPath);

  // Start the Web server
    server.begin();
  }

// The page not found handler
  void handleNotFound(){
    String message = "File not Found\n\n";
    message += "URI: ";
    message += server.uri();
    message += "\nMethod: ";
    message += ( server.method() == HTTP_GET ) ? "GET" : "POST";
    message += "\nArguments: ";
    message += server.args();
    message += "\n";
    server.send(404,"text/plain",message);
  }

//The only valid page handler
  void handleRootPath(){
  //Check to see if values were posted from the form.
    if (server.args()>0){
      if(server.arg("high")){
        highSet=server.arg("high").toFloat();
        if (highSet > MaxSet){
          highSet = MaxSet;
        }
        if (highSet < MinSet){
          highSet = MinSet;
        }
        EEPROM.put(sizeof(float),highSet);
        EEPROM.commit();
      }
      if(server.arg("low")){
        lowSet=server.arg("low").toFloat();
        if(lowSet > MaxSet || lowSet > highSet || lowSet<MinSet){
          lowSet = highSet;
        }
        EEPROM.put(0,lowSet);
        EEPROM.commit();
      }
      if(server.arg("automatic")){
        if(server.arg("automatic")=="checked"){
          automatic="checked";
        } else {
          automatic="unchecked";
        }
      }
      if(server.arg("fan")){
        if(server.arg("fan")=="on"){
          outputRelayState="on";
          digitalWrite(outputLED, LOW);
          digitalWrite(outputRelay, HIGH);
          automatic="unchecked";
        } else {
          if(server.arg("fan")=="off"){
            outputRelayState="off";
            digitalWrite(outputLED, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(outputRelay, LOW);
            automatic="unchecked";
          }
        } 
      }
    //Section to handle changing the password
          if(server.arg("changepass")){
//        if(server.arg("changepass")=="checked"){
//          strcpy(errorMessage,"Old Password Fail");
//        } else {
//          strcpy(errorMessage, "");
//        errorMessage=server.arg("changepass").toCharArray(charBuf,32);
//        }
//          if(server.arg("oldpass")==password){
//            errorMessage="Old Password Match";
//          } else {
//        }
//        }
      }
    }

  //display on/off button depending on state.
    if (strcmp(outputRelayState,"off")==0){
      snprintf(fanButton,100,"<input type='submit' name='fan' value='on' />\n");
    } else {
      snprintf(fanButton,100,"<input type='submit' name='fan' value='off' />\n");
    }

    snprintf(html, 3000,
      "<html>\n"
      "  <head>\n"
      "    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>\n"
      "    <link rel='icon' href='data:,'>\n"
      "    <style>html {font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}\n"
      "      .button { background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;\n"
      "        text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}\n"
      "      .button2 {background-color: #FF3030;}\n"
      "      .on { background-color: #4CAF50;}\n"
      "      .off { background-color: #FF3030;}\n"
      "    </style>\n"
      "    <script>\n"
      "      function reveal() {\n"
      "        var checkBox=document.getElementById('changepass');\n"
      "        var passBox=document.getElementById('passwordBox');\n"
      "        if (checkBox.checked == true){\n"
      "          passBox.style.display='block';\n"
      "        } else {\n"
      "          passBox.style.display='none';\n"
      "        }\n"
      "      }\n"
      "    </script>\n"
      "  </head>\n"
      "  <body>\n"
      "    <h1>HAWK-EYE Technical Services</h1>\n"
      "    <h2>Differential Barametric Pressure Control System</h2>\n"
      "    <form method='post' action='http://192.168.4.1/'>\n"
      "    <table border=0 align=center>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td align=left>Current Temp</td>\n"
      "        <td><textbox> %03.2f </textbox></td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td align=left>Current DP</td>\n"
      "        <td><textbox> %03.2f </textbox></td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td align=left>Low Setpoint</td>\n"
      "        <td><input type='text' name='low' width=8 value=' %03.2f '/></td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td align=left>High Setpoint</td>\n"
      "        <td><input type='text' name='high' width=8 value=' %03.2f '/></td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "    </table>\n"
      "    Automatic: <input type='checkbox' name='automatic' value='checked' %s/><br/>\n"
      "    <input type='checkbox' name='changepass' id='changepass' value='unchecked' onclick='reveal()'/> Change Password<br/>\n"
      "    <table border=0 id='passwordBox' style='display:none'>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td>Old Password</td>\n"
      "        <td><input type='password' name='oldpass' width=8 /></td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td>New Password</td>\n"
      "        <td><input type='password' name='newpass1' width=8 /></td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td>New Password</td>\n"
      "        <td><input type='password' name='newpass2' width=8 /></td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "      <tr>\n"
      "        <td colspan=2>%s</td>\n"
      "      </tr>\n"
      "    </table>\n"
      "    <br/>\n"
      "    <input type='submit' name='fan' value='Set' />\n"
      "    <h1 class='%s'>FAN - State %s </h1>\n"
      "    %s"
      "    </form>\n"
      "%s %s"
      "  </body>\n"
      "</html>",i2cTemp,i2cValue,lowSet,highSet,automatic,errorMessage,outputRelayState,outputRelayState,fanButton,storedPassword,errorMessage);
    server.send(200, "text/html",html);

  }
  void loop() {
  //Start the EEPROM handler so we can write to the EEPROM
    EEPROM.begin(512);

  //Call the client handler
    server.handleClient();

  //Code to read the value from the ADC
    Wire.requestFrom(i2cAddress,5,1);
    if(Wire.available()==5){
      i2cValue = Wire.read();
      i2cValue = i2cValue *256;
      i2cValue = i2cValue+Wire.read();
      i2cCRC = Wire.read();
      i2cTemp = Wire.read();
      i2cTemp = i2cTemp * 256;
      i2cTemp = i2cTemp+Wire.read();
//      i2cCRC = Wire.read();
//      i2cScale = Wire.read() * 256;
//      i2cScale = i2cScale + Wire.read();
//      i2cCRC = Wire.read();
      i2cValue = i2cValue/256;       //conversion factor
      i2cTemp = i2cTemp/i2cTempConv;
    }
    if (strcmp(automatic,"checked")==0 && i2cValue > highSet){
      outputRelayState="on";
      digitalWrite(outputLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(outputRelay, HIGH);
    }
    if (strcmp(automatic,"checked")==0 && i2cValue < lowSet){
      outputRelayState="off";
      digitalWrite(outputLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(outputRelay, LOW);
    }

    delay(100);
  }
```

I have looked through the similar posts but I have not found anything relevant.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Rod

Comment: add more on() handlers. add one for every different html form 'action'. is the form POST? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: If you look down through the code you will find the void handleRootPath() function.  This checks for server arguments. You can see the checks for arguments labeled high, low, automatic, fan and changepass. However, the changepass section, which is commented out in the example, never seems to be valid. This is the section I'm trying to get working.